Do relative clauses modify nouns or noun phrases?
Using "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" by Quirk et al. or "The Longman Student's Grammar of Spoken and Written English" by Biber et al. as a grammatical framework:
Q: Do relative clauses modify just the head noun of a noun phrase or do they modify the rest of the noun phrase where they are contained as a postmodifier?
Example 1: The small guy who is smoking is my brother.
Does the relative clause "who is smoking" modify the head noun "guy" or the rest of the noun phrase "small guy"?
Example 2: We stopped at the big museum in London, which we had never visited before.
Does the relative clause "which we had never visited before" modify the head noun "museum" or "the big museum in London"?
According to the following English Stack Exchange question, the user "John Lawler" states that all relative clauses modify noun phrases, whereas the user "Greg Lee" states that relative clauses modify nouns: adverb or adjective clause
Edit: According to "The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics" by P. H. Matthews:

A clause which modifies the head of a noun phrase ...
E.g. in the man who came, a relative clause who came modifies
man


People can have different opinions on this, but why break up the noun phrase? The red-headed girl who has a tattoo on her arm is my neighbor.   Don't modifiers of a noun become integrated into a more complex NP at some level of language processing?  So the noun girl is at the heart of the NP and the adjective modifier and the integral relative clause unite with the noun to form a more complex NP. A molecular approach seems better to me.

Aren't Q1 and Q2 the same question? Q1 is general, while Q2 is about the specific example.

It depends on your intent.
In both interpretations, we start with a bunch of guys, some of whom may be smoking, and some of whom may be small.
If there are multiple smoking guys, and we want to single out the small one from among them, "who are smoking" only modifies "guy".
If there are multiple small guys, and we want to single out the one that's smoking, "who are smoking" modifies "small guy".
Without context, I think it would be interpreted as

The guy who is both small and smoking

so both the adjective and relative clause modify "guy".

' "who are smoking" modifies guy ' ?

“Noun” is the name for a type of word.
Noun phrase is the term for a word or phrase that can function as the subject or object of a sentence.
Not all nouns are noun phrases: I have changed “guy” to “person” as “Guy” is a name and thus chiefly uncountable.
“The small person who is smoking is my brother”
“The person who is smoking is my brother”
“The person is my brother”
*“Person is my brother”
*“Person is brother"
“Person” and “brother” are nouns but they are not noun phrases.
But
The net interest that came from the investment is 20%
The interest that came from the investment is 20%
The interest is 20%
Interest is 20%.
“Interest” is uncountable and thus capable of being the subject or object in a sentence – it is a noun and a noun phrase.

Do relative clauses modify nouns or noun phrases?

All noun phrases can be replaced by a pronoun:
Q: “Which is your brother?”
A(i): “The small person who is smoking is my brother.”
A(ii): “He who is smoking is him.”
In A(ii), we can see that “who is smoking” modifies “He” -> He represents a noun phrase - "the small person who is smoking", thus “who is smoking” modifies (what is essentially) a noun phrase - in this case, the subject.
Likewise: “The net interest that came from the investment is 20%” -> “That which came from this is 20%”. That represents the noun phrase “The net interest”.

In "the interest" the noun "interest" is not a noun phrase, though. And in "Difficult is how I like my crosswords", the word "difficult" is not a noun phrase.

Sigh... In the first, I did not say that it was - please reread. In the second, there is inversion caused by an adjective. You need to analyse this example

You are using different analyses, gentlemen, without citing the authority you're choosing. Doesn't CGEL posit 'determiner phrases'?

@EdwinAshworth: I haven't checked but "[Generous annual interest accruing constantly] pays for it" has no determiner - perhaps CGEL means something else? The other point is that where authorities disagree, it is open-season.

Looking at “The'That person is my brother” versus  *“Person is my brother”.
